# SQL SELECT Question

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1242

I am trying to perform a `SQL` query that acts in two parts.

First, I have a query that returns a list of 10 Ids.
But then I want to have a `SELECT` statement which has a `WHERE` clause for each of these 10 ids.

Is this possible?

I tried:

```
    SELECT * FROM tablenameWHERE id= (SELECT id FROM table_of_ids WHERE 
    tableid='1a177de1-3f25c9b7910b' OR 
    tableid='64faecca-133af807a65a' OR
... up to 10 Ids)
```

but it returns with an error stating the subquery returns more than 1 row.

Note, the tableid and id columns of table_of_ids are different values.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? 
I seem to be at a loss myself.

If it matters, I am using mySQL and PHP.

Cheers,
Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a very optimized query, but you could use IN instead of =

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table_of_ids WHERE 
    tableid='1a177de1-3f25c9b7910b' OR 
    tableid='64faecca-133af807a65a' OR
... up to 10 Ids)
```

Comment: How might you suggest optimizing it?

Answer (score 2):

Change it to in()

```
WHERE id IN (SELECT id ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `=` with the `IN` keyword.

```
select * from sometable where key in (subselect that returns one column)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can;

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
  INNER JOIN table_of_ids ON table_of_ids.id = tablename.id
WHERE table_of_ids.tableid IN (
  '1a177de1-3f25c9b7910b',
  '64faecca-133af807a65a',
... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the "=" operator, use the "IN" operator.
See this [tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlin.php) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use IN keyword.

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE Id IN(SELECT userId FROM table).
```

Id is primary key of your first table and userId is foreign key in second table of coz.